How to fix Aggregate Measurements method in order to display properly?
I am working on a Blazor application for weight measurement. Data is coming from a third-party device in real time. I have this weighing results component on my dashboard that I am trying to display on a grid according to some rules. The data grid periodically loads data from a database.
Aggregate Measurements will calculate the weighing data of the client (Oğulbey, Yeşilköy) based on the plate number (06GG111, 34HH222) current day in date time descending order. There might be trend changes as you can see on the 2-day sample data. Measurement starts from 3000 for Oğulbey,06GG111and goes up to 4224 on 2024-11-27. (It is the first sequence) Then it goes down to 3000 for Oğulbey,06GG111 again on the same day, and goes to 4068. (It is the second sequence) This is the definition of trend change. (Same as the decrease)
Here is a 2-day sample data set
**3000  2024-11-26 16:45:49 Oğulbey     06GG111
3345    2024-11-26 16:45:56 Yeşilköy    34HH222
3426    2024-11-26 16:46:56 Oğulbey     06GG111
3771    2024-11-26 16:47:26 Yeşilköy    34HH222**
3000    2024-11-27 16:59:27 Oğulbey     06GG111
3345    2024-11-27 16:59:48 Yeşilköy    34HH222
3661    2024-11-27 17:00:27 Oğulbey     06GG111
4006    2024-11-27 17:00:40 Yeşilköy    34HH222
4224    2024-11-27 17:01:27 Oğulbey     06GG111
3000    2024-11-27 17:04:11 Oğulbey     06GG111
3345    2024-11-27 17:04:30 Yeşilköy    34HH222
3530    2024-11-27 17:05:11 Oğulbey     06GG111
3875    2024-11-27 17:05:24 Yeşilköy    34HH222
4068    2024-11-27 17:06:11 Oğulbey     06GG111

expected output:

Second sequence because of trend change
3000    4068    2024-11-27 17:06:11 Oğulbey     06GG111
3345    3875    2024-11-27 17:05:24 Yeşilköy    34HH222
first sequence
3000    4224    2024-11-27 17:01:27 Oğulbey     06GG111
3345    4006    2024-11-27 17:00:40 Yeşilköy    34HH222
previous day
3345    3771    2024-11-26 16:47:26 Yeşilköy    34HH222
3000    3426    2024-11-26 16:46:56 Oğulbey     06GG111

Here is the component but it does not give the expected output.
@page "/weighing-results"
@using OfficeOpenXml
@using OfficeOpenXml.Style
@using Radzen
@using Radzen.Blazor
@using WeighingDeviceDashboard.Service
@inject IMeasurementService MeasurementService
@inject IJSRuntime JS
<style>
    .highlight {
        animation: blink 1s alternate 5; /* Adjust duration, iterations, and timing as needed */
        /* animation-fill-mode: forwards; */
        animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1);
    }
    @@keyframes blink {
        0% {
            background-color: #ff0000; /* Yellow (highlight color) */
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        50% {
            background-color: #ffffff; /* White (default background color) */
        }
        100% {
            background-color: #ff0000; /* Yellow (highlight color) */
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    }
</style>
<RadzenButton Text="Export" Icon="grid_on" Click="@(args => ExportExcel())" Class="mb-4 mr-2" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Secondary" Size="ButtonSize.Small" />
<RadzenDataGrid @ref=grid Data="@weighingResults" TItem="WeighingResult" AllowFiltering="true" AllowColumnResize="false" AllowAlternatingRows="true"
                FilterMode="FilterMode.Advanced" AllowSorting="true" PageSize="15" AllowPaging="true" AllowGrouping="true" PagerHorizontalAlign="HorizontalAlign.Left"
                ShowPagingSummary="true" ColumnWidth="300px" LogicalFilterOperator="LogicalFilterOperator.And"
                IsLoading=@isLoading Sort="@ShowLoading" Page="@ShowLoading" Group="@ShowLoading" Filter="@ShowLoading">
    <Columns>
        <RadzenDataGridColumn Property="@nameof(WeighingResult.ClientId)" Title="Warehouse" Width="150px" />
        <RadzenDataGridColumn Property="@nameof(WeighingResult.PlateNumber)" Title="Plate Number" Width="150px">
            <Template Context="result">
                <span class="@((result as WeighingResult).IsNew? "highlight" : "")">@result.PlateNumber</span>
            </Template>
        </RadzenDataGridColumn>
        <RadzenDataGridColumn Property="@nameof(WeighingResult.FirstWeighingValue)" Title="First Weighing (KG)" Width="200px">
            <Template Context="result">
                <span>@result.FirstWeighingValue.ToString("F0")</span>
            </Template>
        </RadzenDataGridColumn>
        <RadzenDataGridColumn Property="@nameof(WeighingResult.LastWeighingValue)" Title="Last Weighing (KG)" Width="200px">
            <Template Context="result">
                <span>@result.LastWeighingValue.ToString("F0")</span>
            </Template>
        </RadzenDataGridColumn>
        <RadzenDataGridColumn Property="@nameof(WeighingResult.WeightDifference)" Title="Weight Difference (KG)" Width="230px">
            <Template Context="result">
                <span class="@((result as WeighingResult).IsNew? "highlight" : "")">
                    @(result.WeightDifference!= null? 
                        (result.WeightDifference > 0? $"+{result.WeightDifference.Value.ToString("F0")}" : 
                            (result.WeightDifference < 0? $"{result.WeightDifference.Value.ToString("F0")}" : $"0")) 
                        : "-")
                </span>
            </Template>
        </RadzenDataGridColumn>
        <RadzenDataGridColumn Property="@nameof(WeighingResult.LastWeighingDateTime)" Title="Last Weighing Date Time" Width="200px" />
        <RadzenDataGridColumn Property="@nameof(WeighingResult.ReceiptNo)" Title="Receipt Number" Width="200px" />
    </Columns>
</RadzenDataGrid>
@code {
    RadzenDataGrid<WeighingResult> grid = new();
    List<WeighingResult> weighingResults = new List<WeighingResult>();
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _measurementLock = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
    bool isLoading = false;
    private CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource;
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
        _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        await LoadDataPeriodically(_cancellationTokenSource.Token);
    }
    private async Task LoadDataPeriodically(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await ShowLoading();
            weighingResults = await GetWeighingResultsAsync();
            await grid.Reload();
            StateHasChanged(); // Ensure UI updates
            try
            {
                await Task.Delay(60000, cancellationToken); // 1,2 minutes delay
            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException)
            {
                // Task was canceled, exit the loop
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    private async Task ShowLoading()
    {
        isLoading = true;
        await Task.Yield();
        isLoading = false;
    }
    private async Task<List<WeighingResult>> GetWeighingResultsAsync()
    {
        await _measurementLock.WaitAsync();
        try
        {
            var measurements = await MeasurementService.GetMeasurementsAsync();
            return AggregateMeasurements(measurements);
        }
        finally
        {
            _measurementLock.Release();
        }
    }
    private List<WeighingResult> AggregateMeasurements(IEnumerable<Measurement> measurements)
    {
        var results = new List<WeighingResult>();
        var current_date = DateTime.Now.Date;
        var measurementGroups = measurements
            .GroupBy(m => (m.ClientId, m.PlateNumber, m.Timestamp.Date))
            .Select(g => new
            {
                Group = g.OrderBy(m => m.Timestamp).ToList(),
                ClientId = g.Key.ClientId,
                PlateNumber = g.Key.PlateNumber,
                Date = g.Key.Date
            });
        foreach (var groupInfo in measurementGroups)
        {
            int sequence = 1;
            Trend? currentTrend = null;
            Measurement? previousMeasurement = null;
            WeighingResult? currentResult = null;
            foreach (var measurement in groupInfo.Group)
            {
                var currentValue = (float)measurement.Value;
                // Determine trend
                Trend? newTrend = null;
                if (previousMeasurement != null)
                {
                    var previousValue = (float)previousMeasurement.Value;
                    newTrend = GetTrend(previousValue, currentValue);
                }
                // Check for trend change
                if (previousMeasurement != null && newTrend != currentTrend)
                {
                    // Create a new result when trend changes
                    sequence++;
                    currentResult = new WeighingResult
                        {
                            ClientId = measurement.ClientId,
                            PlateNumber = measurement.PlateNumber,
                            FirstWeighingValue = currentValue,
                            LastWeighingValue = currentValue,
                            LastWeighingDateTime = measurement.Timestamp,
                            ReceiptNo = measurement.ReceiptNo,
                            WeighingSequence = sequence,
                            IsNew = true // Mark as new for highlighting
                        };
                    results.Add(currentResult);
                }
                else if (currentResult == null)
                {
                    // Create the first result
                    currentResult = new WeighingResult
                        {
                            ClientId = measurement.ClientId,
                            PlateNumber = measurement.PlateNumber,
                            FirstWeighingValue = currentValue,
                            LastWeighingValue = currentValue,
                            LastWeighingDateTime = measurement.Timestamp,
                            ReceiptNo = measurement.ReceiptNo,
                            WeighingSequence = sequence,
                            IsNew = true // Mark as new for highlighting
                        };
                    results.Add(currentResult);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Update existing result
                    if (currentValue < currentResult.FirstWeighingValue)
                    {
                        currentResult.FirstWeighingValue = currentValue;
                    }
                    if (currentValue > currentResult.LastWeighingValue)
                    {
                        currentResult.LastWeighingValue = currentValue;
                        currentResult.LastWeighingDateTime = measurement.Timestamp;
                        currentResult.ReceiptNo = measurement.ReceiptNo;
                    }
                }
                // Update trend tracking
                currentTrend = newTrend;
                previousMeasurement = measurement;
            }
        }
        // Sort results by date and sequence
        return results
            .OrderByDescending(r => r.LastWeighingDateTime)
            .ThenBy(r => r.WeighingSequence)
            .ToList();
    }
    private Trend? GetTrend(float previousValue, float currentValue)
    {
        if (currentValue > previousValue) return Trend.Increasing;
        if (currentValue < previousValue) return Trend.Decreasing;
        return null;
    }
    private enum Trend
    {
        Increasing,
        Decreasing
    }
    private async Task ExportExcel()
    {
        var filter = grid.View;
        ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        using (var package = new ExcelPackage(stream))
        {
            var workSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Weighing Results");
            var recordIndex = 2;
            workSheet.Row(1).Style.Font.Bold = true;
            var headerCells = workSheet.Cells["A1:G1"];
            headerCells.Style.Font.Bold = true;
            headerCells.Style.Font.Size = 13;
            headerCells.Style.Border.BorderAround(ExcelBorderStyle.Thin);
            headerCells.Style.Border.Top.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
            headerCells.Style.Border.Left.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
            headerCells.Style.Border.Right.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
            headerCells.Style.Border.Bottom.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
            headerCells.Style.Font.Color.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.Black);
            headerCells.Style.Fill.PatternType = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
            headerCells.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.LightGray);
            workSheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "Warehouse";
            workSheet.Cells[1, 2].Value = "Plate Number";
            workSheet.Cells[1, 3].Value = "First Weighing Value";
            workSheet.Cells[1, 4].Value = "Last Weighing Value";
            workSheet.Cells[1, 5].Value = "Weight Difference";
            workSheet.Cells[1, 6].Value = "Last Weighing Date Time";
            workSheet.Cells[1, 7].Value = "Receipt Number";
            foreach (var result in filter)
            {
                workSheet.Cells[recordIndex, 1].Value = result.ClientId;
                workSheet.Cells[recordIndex, 2].Value = result.PlateNumber;
                workSheet.Cells[recordIndex, 3].Value = result.FirstWeighingValue.ToString("F0");
                workSheet.Cells[recordIndex, 4].Value = result.LastWeighingValue.ToString("F0");
                workSheet.Cells[recordIndex, 5].Value = result.WeightDifference?.ToString("F0");
                workSheet.Cells[recordIndex, 6].Value = result.LastWeighingDateTime.ToString("g");
                workSheet.Cells[recordIndex, 7].Value = result.ReceiptNo;
                recordIndex++;
            }
            workSheet.Cells[workSheet.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns();
            await package.SaveAsync();
        }
        stream.Position = 0;
        var excelName = $"Weighing Results-{DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyHHmm")}.xlsx";
        using var streamRef = new DotNetStreamReference(stream: stream);
        await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("downloadFileFromStream", excelName, streamRef);
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        _cancellationTokenSource?.Cancel();
        _cancellationTokenSource?.Dispose();
    }
}

